# How to order a Django query set, when only want one observation at the end?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a observation, "Other" that I want at the end of a queryset of other objects. However, if I order it alphabetic or any other way, "Other" comes in the middle. How do I make "Other" last?

```
Queryset.objects.order_by('-names_of_objects')

"sdnlks", "dklnldsk", "Other", "dfsdno", "cdksnodi", "cjsdkc"
```

Instead I want:

```
"sdnlks", "dklnldsk", "dfsdno", "cdksnodi", "cjsdkc", "Other"
```

I don't care about the other objects order.

Comment: Do you want to sort it alphabetically?  What sorting you want in output?

Comment: No sorting, just other at the end

Comment: To add to end to a list you can use `append` you can pop the Other and append

Comment: Queryset not python list, if you can do this with a query set please show me how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`extra`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#extra) method with a `select` argument that specifies a raw SQL expression as an additional field to order by:

```
Queryset.objects.extra(select={'is_other': "names_of_objects = 'Other'"}, order_by=['is_other'])
```